# Vue custom directive to simulate getter/setter of computed property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

There is an input tag when user type something, I want to add some symbols to the input value. Well, when I need the real value I should remove those symbols from the value. I know I can achieve this using computed property like following:

```vuejs
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="computedTest" /><!-- shows 20$ -->
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      test: 20,
    }
  },

  computed: {
    computedTest: {
      get() {
        return this.test + "$"
      },
      set(val) {
        this.test = this.val.replace(/$/g, "")
      },
    },

    methods: {
      doSomething() {
        console.log(this.test) // 20
      },
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Since Vuejs can do this using computed property feature, I believe I can achieve this feature using custom directive. But, I have no idea of the way to do. This is the first try what I did:

```vuejs
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="test" v-custom />
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            test: 0
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

And the code for v-custom directive:

```js
export default {
  bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    Vue.set(el, "value", toLanguage(el.value, "en")) // toLanguage is a custom function
  },

  componentUpdated: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    // getContext is a custom function and the `contextObj` variable will be equal to
    // the whole data property of the component context and the `model` will be equal to 
    // the v-model expression (in this example, `test`).
    let { contextObj, model } = getContext(vnode)

    const vnodeValue = get(contextObj, model) // lodash `get` function

    // parsing v-model value to remove symbols
    const parsedValue = parseInputValue(el, vnodeValue) ?? vnodeValue

    if (contextObj) {
      Vue.set(contextObj, model, parsedValue)
    }

    el.value = toLanguage(el.value, "en")

    el.dispatchEvent(new Event("input", { bubbles: true }))
  },
}
```

But this directive snippet **creates an infinite loop**. I'm using **Vue2.x**. I'll appreciate anybody can help.

Comment: What is the version of vue?

Comment: @NehaSoni Vue2.x